# How to trigger an email on spring boot application startup failure

Tags: spring-boot

I have multiple spring boot applications. I need to trigger an email to specific mailid, if application starts to fail. I have tried with failure analyzer but couldn't able to trigger an email

Comment: Do you have trouble to detect failure or to send an email ?

Comment: I have to send an email with the reason for failure.

Comment: Ex: If application fails to start for running application twice on same port, Email should be triggered like, Application failed to start because port already in use

Comment: Guide for [sending an email](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-email)